# GCC doesn't tail call optimize recursive function

Tags: c, gcc, tail-recursion

I have written a hexadecimal-parsing function for my uint128 structure, which is internally just two uint64_t's - hi and lo. Here's the function in question:

```
uint128_t parse_from_hex(const char *string, uint128_t previous_value, const size_t num_digits) {
    if (string == NULL || string[0] == '\0')
        return previous_value;

    if (num_digits + 1 > 2 * SIZEOF_INT128) { // SIZEOF_INT128 is 16 - meaning 16 bytes
        return UINT128_MAX; // the maximum value of 128bit uint, if we overflow
    }

    int64_t current_digit = parse_hex_digit(string[0]);
    if (current_digit < 0)
        return UINT128_ZERO; // a global variable which I use multiple times which represents a 0
    return parse_from_hex(string + 1,
                          uint128_or_uint64(uint128_shift_left(previous_value, 4), (uint64_t)current_digit),
                          num_digits + 1);
}
```

For some reason, gcc does not optimize the function even though the recursive call is clearly made a single time at the end of the function. The other functions used in the parsing function don't have any side effects and return a new value, so I do not think that the problem is with them. I have tried making the uint128_t struct members non-const (originally they were non-const) as well as the function arguments non-const, but that didn't help either. Originally compiled with Ofast, but also tried with O3 and O2 - no luck. Could anyone who knows better on the subject please help? I thought I understood it quite well but clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: Is there any reason you'd do this recursively? This is a job for a loop.

Comment: Here's a godbolt link showing the original code not being tail recursive: https://godbolt.org/z/Ws4YTz

Comment: GCC 10.2 will do tail recursion here, Clang doesn't.

Comment: What version of compiler isn't doing the tail call optimization?

Comment: @tadman Not really any specific reason in making this recursive, I was just testing and started wondering why the compiler didn't optimize it - seems like the problem really was the fact that I used clang, not actually gcc

Comment: @BillLynch yes, seems like the problem is that I've actually used clang, which for some reason doesn't optimize it. Thanks!

Comment: GCC does have an easier time optimizing and in many cases unrolling loops than dealing with tail recursion which is more of a functional programming pattern. The optimizer deals with patterns people use most frequently. Even optimized this code looks like it's a lot more complicated than a loop-based version of same.

Comment: For fun a non-recursive approach `uint128_t parse_from_hex(const char *string) {
uint128_t sum = 0; if (string) { while (*string) { int current_digit =  parse_hex_digit(*string); if (current_digit < 0) { return 0; } if (sum > UINT128_MAX / 16) { return UINT128_MAX;  } sum = sum * 16 + (current_digit & 15); string++; } } return sum;`
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been pointed out by @BillLynch in the comments - it's clang which doesn't optimize the function for some reason, not GCC. On my PC GCC 10.2.0 optimizes the function properly, so there's no problem here.